# TeamCity run after deployment

Tags: deployment, powershell, teamcity

I make the deployment site with TeamCity. Today there is a need to deploy the WCF service running in a console application. I see it this way: a .ps1 deployment script which stop my service process, copy new files to the service app dir, adding task to scheduller to run the console application on startup, run tasks manualy. But buildAgent user (which make deploy) have to privileges to use scheduller.

Is there simple way to start deployed application under SYSTEM or just another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use runas.

```
runas /user:useraccount@domain.com "c:\folder\yourprogram.exe"
```

Or lsrunas http://www.moernaut.com/default.aspx?item=lsrunas

Or lsrunase: http://www.moernaut.com/default.aspx?item=lsrunase

Or you could create a service which is starting the program. But this is a more complicated approach.

Comment: RunAs require typing password interactive, I need a silent solution.

Comment: @Evl-ntnt for a scripting approach lsrunas is the simplest variant.